# BleachBit 3.0 does not support Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: bleachbit

I'm trying to update BleachBit 2.0 to 3.0. I've downloaded the .deb package from the [official site](https://www.bleachbit.org/download/file/t?file=bleachbit_3.0_all_ubuntu1604.deb), but it requires `python-scandir`.

I installed `python-scandir` from [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/) for Debian, and BleachBit 3.0 was successfully installed.

But it does not work and I get some exceptions (white list).
What to do?

Comment: Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1187899/edit) your question and add the exceptions you get?

Answer (score 0):

The python-scandir is a [known issue documented in the release notes](https://www.bleachbit.org/news/bleachbit-30#known) for BleachBit 3.0. There is a link there to an issue ticket that has a link to a pre-release of an official .deb with a fix.

Alternatively, you could download the [older version BleachBit 2.2](https://www.bleachbit.org/download/old).

The pkgs.org site has an ancient BleachBit version 1.10. Please be careful not to use ancient versions such as this. Each version of Ubuntu (e.g., 16.04) does not update BleachBit, so it is best to get the official version from the BleachBit site.